# Building a Dynamic Website with Mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, dynamic, web

**Intro**

Hello! I am in the process of building a lyrics website where I will store the lyrics in a MySQL database.

I want to have 2 main tables: 1 for the lyrics which will have id, lyrics title, lyrics text, **artist name**,and number of views.

The other table will be the artist table with: id, **artist name**

**QUESTIONS:**

1. How can I link the two tables by using the artist name field in both table?  I want to display all the artists on my site from the table and see all the lyrics related to that particular artist/
2. How can I link to a particular record or field in a table?

Please help or if you know of any sites or videos that can help me learn these and other things that may help me in building my site would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer first question.
You should really change your lyrics table using an `id_artist` field instead of `artist name`.
This makes sure you don't duplicate names (so wasting space) and you can't write a wrong name leading you to wrong result during queries.
So you can do

```
SELECT a.`artist name`, l.title, l.text
FROM artist a INNER JOIN lyrics l
ON a.id = l.id_artist
WHERE a.name = '....'
// or you can use WHERE a.id = ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not store the artist name in both tables.  That defeats the purpose of having a separate artist table.  Instead store the ArtistID in the Lyrics table, and only store the ArtistName in the Artist table.  That way if you, for example, misspell an artist's name, you will only have to update one table, and you will not break the relationship between Lyrics and Artist.

Tables are linked together using [Foreign Key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) relations.